# There is no implicit reference conversion from 'WSS_Common.Helper.ApplicationUser' to 'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityUser'?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I've changed the Primary Key for Users in ASP.NET Identity following 
[this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/identity/overview/extensibility/change-primary-key-for-users-in-aspnet-identity) and after successfully completing that I'm getting the [following errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0gxgP.png).

I've tried GetUserId but it's not working.

Here is the error in WSSCONTEXT.cs

```html
public class Context : Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public Context() : base("name=Context")
        {
            System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer(
                new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<Context,
                WSS_Common.Migrations.Configuration>("Context")
                );
        }
```

and the error pointing identityConfig.cs

```html
 public class ApplicationUserManager : UserManager<ApplicationUser,int>
    {
        public ApplicationUserManager(IUserStore<ApplicationUser,int> store)
            : base(store)
        {
        }
```